# Can I setup a "Connect" webhook with a self-signed ssl certificate?

Tags: docusignapi

I set up a docusign webhook but it's not getting any posts. Could it be because I'm using a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: is the problem that I'm using a self-signed cert?

Correct.

DocuSign requires that the customer's server use an SSL cert that chains to a CA listed in the Microsoft list of trusted CAs.

You can use a free cert from the [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) project or any low cost cert. You should not pay more than $8 for 1 year.

Some ISPs offer a better deal to their customers.

Some articles about setting up Connect:

**Use SIM mode**
[Using Connect’s New Send Individual Messages Feature](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-connect-send-individual-messages/)

**Security** [Securing Your Connect Webhook Listener](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-securing-connect-webhook-listener/)

Comment: Thank you, Larry, I'll try that.
But I've also tried to set up a webhook by including an `eventNotification` object when creating an envelope. According to the documentation, HTTP should work for this in the demo account but it is not working for me. 
What could it be?

Comment: The docs are out of date. HTTPS is now required for Connect customers' servers on demo (developer sandbox) and production. Please let me know in a comment where the out of date information is and I'll update it. Many thanks, Larry